# How to make query string readable in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to make this string readable in Python 2.7?

%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_2016-2020_%D0%B3%D0%B3

This string contains Cyrillic symbol and it's a part of a URL (a query string parameter).

Comment: I'd suggest seeing if you can import those symbols / language pack into python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [urllib.unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) from the standard library.

> **urllib.unquote(string)¶**
>
> Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.
>
> Example: unquote('/%7Econnolly/') yields '/~connolly/'.